# How to change RootViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing some custom camera app, I just want to skip my login page and make my camera home page to initial root view when  user already registered. I'm doing it from AppDelegate or inside the view code however I'm getting an error any one described it from scratch or any sample example. My code is below,

Codes are in `viewDidLoad`

If I am trying below code in `AppDelegate` then also its occurs problem

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![defaults boolForKey:@"registered"])
{
    NSLog(@"no user register");

    ViewController *loginview = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = loginview;        
}
else
{        
    NSLog(@"user is registered");

    CameraHome *camview = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraHome"];
    self.window.rootViewController = camview;
}
```

Any one can please describe how to skip that view if I'm already registered and switch directly to my homepage.

Comment: "Lots of error", such as...?

Comment: app terminates with bug panel

Comment: I think you should not change the rootview controller instead you should create any pop up for login screen or etc. you root screen should always be a main screen not login screen

Comment: Show the error, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    // check if user is already Logged in
    if([defaults objectForKey:@"username"]!=nil  && ![[defaults objectForKey:@"username"] isEqualToString:@""]){

        UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *view = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];

        [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: i am already checked the condition i just want to switch to my home page when app load

Comment: Just try this method on your Login , i guess it will work for you .

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle </Users/moeenahmad/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1A3BAC03-4478-4733-97EB-0C54A2456C34/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CD2F716-7628-4207-8F04-BF06544BA2A0/cameraroll1.1.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @moeen : Whats your storyboard name , You are inserting wrong name .

Answer (score 1):

```
in .h file
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *objUINavigationController;

in .m file

NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![defaults boolForKey:@"registered"])
{
ViewController *objViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

self.objUINavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objViewController];

[self.window setRootViewController:self.objUINavigationController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
else
{
    CameraHome *camview = [[CameraHome alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraHome" bundle:nil];

    self.objUINavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:camview];

[self.window setRootViewController:self.objUINavigationController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: may i have to import camera header file at my view controller current in this all code are cause without it it showing error on else part

Comment: cameraroll1.1[944:51789] -[ViewController window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78759010
2014-12-29 04:20:19.250 cameraroll1.1[944:51789] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78759010'
*** First throw call stack:    i am getting this error

Comment: i did that then after its not working throwing above error with camera home navigation controller is attached is that reason for not connectivity properly or what

Comment: The pushViewController:animated: method is a method of UINavigationController.

But your root view controller is of type ViewController which is most likely a UIViewController.

You need to change your setup so your main view controller is inside a UINavigationController and you need to make the navigation controller the window's root view controller.

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: still login page appears after i did same as above and some the error of nav controller and nd import header file

Comment: yes in my story board my root view controller is login page in viewcontroller

Comment: select the login controller in stroyboard then select from menu...
1)Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller

Comment: yup i already did that but still its not navigating to camera home